# Display values in td after click on it

Tags: javascript

Lets say I got a `<td>` which got some with some values in it, for example:

```
<td onclick = "insertItem(this)" time = "8:00" day = "Monday"></td>
```

Then when I click i want my div to show these times, for example:

```
<div id = "show">
  <p><strong> #DAY </strong> #time </p>
</div>
```

Then my script goes like this:

```
function insertItem(x) {               
  var time = x.time;
  var day = x.day;
}
```

Transfer somehow?!? :)

Comment: Sidenot jquery is accepted aswell

Comment: Check out **reactjs**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is this?

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].onclick = function(e){
 if(e.target.tagName != "TD"){return;}
 var show = document.getElementById("show");
 
 // Save Attributes
 show.dataset.day = e.target.dataset.day;
 show.dataset.hour = e.target.dataset.hour;
 show.dataset.minutes = e.target.dataset.minutes;
 
 //Show Attributes
 show.innerHTML = "<p><strong>Day: "+
  e.target.dataset.day+
  "</strong> Time: "+
  e.target.dataset.hour+
  ":"+
  e.target.dataset.minutes+
  "</p>";
};
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-day="10" data-hour="8" data-minutes="00">8:00</td>
    <td data-day="14" data-hour="9" data-minutes="15">9:15</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<span id="show"></span>
```

Comment: This works, although the use of invalid html attributes in Filip's code should be addressed somehow, such as by adding `data-` to the attribute names, and accessed via the `dataset.<fieldName>` syntax. Example: `<td data-day="10"...></td>`, then can be accessed via: `e.target.dataset.day` in your function.

Comment: yeah, when I inspict the span tag my values are not transfered im afraid

Comment: @chris thanks, it's something I didn't know. I have changed it.

Comment: @Filip I do not understand what failure you get, could you explain more?

Comment: I want my atribute and values in td tag "time" "day" to be inserted into the span tag aswell

Comment: He modified the example. Tell me if I understood correctly.